# obtener solo datos de fila seleccionada en tree grid Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

tengo una lista la cual debe ser mostrada en un tree grid pero que asi mismo al seleccionar un item de este mismo me arroje los datos del mismo. ya puedo mostrar la lista pero al momento de intentar obtener solo los datos del registro que necesito para imprimir no lo logro enviar con la funcion click

[image: Este es el tree grid cargado]

y este es el codigo que tengo implementado:

HTML:

```
<db-angular-tree-grid #angularGrid (click)="seleccionArbol($event.target)" [data]="data" [configs]="configs"></db-angular-tree-grid>
```

Typescript:

```
seleccionArbol(dato){
var row = dato;
debugger;
```

}

y esta es la lista:

```
data: any = [
{ id: 1, name: 'Bimal', age: 60, weight: 60, gender: 1, phone: 7930343463, parent: 0},
{ id: 2, name: 'Bhagi', age: 40, weight: 95, gender: 1, phone: 7930343463, parent: 1},
{ id: 3, name: 'Kalyana', age: 36, weight: 105, gender: 1, phone: 7930343463, parent: 1},
{ id: 4, name: 'Prakash', age: 20, weight: 20, gender: 1, phone: 7930343463, parent: 2},
{ id: 5, name: 'Jitu', age: 21, weight: 61, gender: 1, phone: 7930343463, parent: 3},
{ id: 6, name: 'Sunil', age: 60, weight: 87, gender: 1, phone: 7930343463, parent: 34},
{ id: 7, name: 'Tadit', age: 40, weight: 60, gender: 1, phone: 7930343463, parent: 6},
{ id: 8, name: 'Suraj', age: 36, weight: 60, gender: 1, phone: 7930343463, parent: 6},
{ id: 9, name: 'Swarup', age: 20, weight: 40, gender: 1, phone: 7930343463, parent: 8},
{ id: 10, name: 'Lakin', age: 21, weight: 55, gender: 1, phone: 7930343463, parent: 8},
```

];

basicamente lo que necesito es que si selecciono el iem uno solo poder obtener los datos de ese item y no la totalidad de los datos del tree grid.

Comment: podrías poner la información que te aparece cuando haces click y el resto del código de tu componente?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo la libreria tiene un evento y lo solucione con el evento "(rowselect)="seleccionArbol($event);"" este permite obtener los datos de la fila seleccionada